# How do I access the Git included in microclimate?

Tags: microclimate

I want to use microclimate **installed on ICP** with my local IDE and not the web IDE provided. How do I and my team access the GitLab to work on the code generated by microclimate? How do I commit my changes using my local IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on how to integrate with your existing IDEs using the following url:
https://microclimate-dev2ops.github.io/howToIDE

Additionally, you can also import your project from GitLab and/or GitHub using the Import Project option and referencing the git repo location. To enable bi-directional code change between Microclimate and GIT, you need to run MicroClimate on ICP and enable the Pipeline.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply but it doesn't work for what I want to do. I want to setup an devops environment for a team to build a project with microclimate and ICP. The instructions you've sent are for a local installation of microclimate.

Answer (score 0):

Microclimate does not provide GitLab, but it will work with GitLab. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/kubernetes/gitlab_chart.html provides instructions for installing GitLab onto Kubernetes. Once set up you should be able to interact with GitLab from your local IDE in the same way as you would with any other git server.